# Variable indefinida y está definida

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario en donde tengo un input que recibe un valor y al presionar buscar me traer todos los campos de la tabla y funciona correcto, pero al abrir la página me dice que tengo una variable indefinida, me pueden ayudar a saber que es lo incorrecto que estoy haciendo?

Adjunto el código que tengo

```
 
<html lamg="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-widch, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>    
    <body style="background-color: darkgrey">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <center><img style="width: 205px; height: 205px;" alt="" src="imagenes/Captura.JPG">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center>   
  
<form method="post" action="consultas.php">
    
                    <?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","dipreca");
$rut_rut=$_POST["rutingreso"];
$productos= "SELECT* from imponentes WHERE rut ='$rut_rut'";
?>     
    
<div class="container"  width = 80%>
              
    <table class="table table-bordered mt-2">

        <thead>
            <caption class="caption-top">Datos del Beneficiario</caption>
            <tr>
   
<p>

      <br> <br> <br> <br>

    Buscar Rut: <input type="search" name="rutingreso" >

    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">

  </p>                
                
<th >Op o Mail</th>
<th  >Fecha de ingreso de Op</th>
    <th  >Oficio</th>
    <th  >N° de resolución</th>
    <th >Apellidos</th>
    <th  >Nombres</th>
    <th  >Rut</th>
     <th  >Institución</th>
    <th  >Tipo de Beneficios</th>
    <th  >Inicio de Pensión</th>
    <th  >Asignación familiar</th>
    <th  >Proceso</th>  
    <th  >Mes de Pago</th>
    <th  >Dia de Pago</th>
    <th  >Observaciones</th>
    <th  >Correo</th>    
     </tr>
    </thead>    
    
    <?php 

$resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $productos);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 ?>
<tbody>
<th ><?php echo $row["opomail"];?></th>
    
    <th ><?php echo $row["ingresodeop"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["oficio"];
     ?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["nresolucion"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["apellidos"];?></th>
   <th ><?php echo $row["nombres"];?></th>
     <th ><?php echo $row["rut"];?></th>
 <th ><?php echo $row["institucion"];?></th>
      <th ><?php echo $row["tipobeneficios"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["iniciopension"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["grado"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["npension"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["asignacionfamiliar"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["proceso"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["mespago"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["diapago"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["observaciones"];?></th>
    
    
    <th ><?php echo $row["correo"];?></th>
   
   
    </tbody>
<?php }mysqli_free_result($resultado);?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    
     
             </table>   

</div>  
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input onclick="location.href='index.html' " value="Volver" type="button"><br>        
        
    </form>           
              
        </body>    
   </html>
```

---

[image: error]

este es el error que me arroja en la variable rutingreso

---

aparece este error ahora[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la linea 123 es el cierre del html

Comment: Pon el error exacto que te da por favor y cambia esto `<html lang="es">` es con N no con M.

Comment: Que tal, en sí, que es lo que dice el log sobre el error?

Comment: No es un mensaje de variable indefinida, sino un *undefined index*, el cual ocurre cuando intentas buscar en un array un valor con una clave que no existe. Cuando abres por vez  primera ese archivo, no habrá nada en `$_POST` porque el formulario no se habrá enviado en la primera apertura de la página. Para evitarlo, usa fusión de null en este caso: `$rut_rut=$_POST["rutingreso"] ?? null;  if ($rut_rut) { /* ... aquí el resto de tu código ... */ }` Aunque ¡estamos en 2024! y hoy ya no se programa como lo haces aquí. Piensa en usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.